# How to perform SFTP operations using PHP after disabling deprecated ciphers on CentOS5?

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, deprecated, centos5

I have PHP code for SFTP operations which is working fine on a CentOS5 machine currently.
After disabling the following deprecated ciphers, it stopped working.

Here is the list of ciphers

Key Exchange: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers: arcfour256, arcfour128, 3DES-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc,   arcfour

Here is the current code snippet

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('ftp_url', 'ftp_port');
```

Comment: "it stopped working" This is vague. What exactly happens? Do you get error messages? What do they say?

Comment: Consider using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. This approach actually enforces code to use specified ciphers

```
$methods = array(
         'hostkey'                 => 'ssh-rsa,ssh-dss',
         'client_to_server'        => array(
                 'crypt'  => 'aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc',
                 'comp'   => 'none'
         ),
         'server_to_client'        => array(
                 'crypt'  => 'aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc',
                 'comp'   => 'none'
         )
);

$connection = ssh2_connect( 'ftp_url', 'ftp_port', $methods );
```